# tar extraction errors on NFS : "Can't create ... OR Could not stat ..."

Tags: mount, nfs, tar

I need to install homebrew on a Macmini6,2 on which I don't have the admin rights and cannot write in /usr/local so I try to extract brew-1.7.1.tar.gz in $HOME (which is mounted in an NFS).

But then I get many tar extraction errors on NFS : "Can't create ... OR Could not stat ...", here are the details :

```bash
$ gunzip brew-1.7.1.tar.gz
$ tar tf brew-1.7.1.tar >/dev/null
$ echo $?
0
$ tar xf brew-1.7.1.tar | egrep "Could not stat|Can't create"
brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/c99: Can't create 'brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/c99'
brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/cc: Can't create 'brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/cc'
brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/clang: Can't create 'brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/clang'
brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/clang++: Can't create 'brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/clang++'
brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/cpp: Can't create 'brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/cpp'
brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/g++: Can't create 'brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/g++'
brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/g++-4.2: Can't create 'brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/g++-4.2'
brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/g++-4.3: Can't create 'brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/g++-4.3'
brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/g++-4.4: Can't create 'brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/g++-4.4'
brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/g++-4.5: Can't create 
...
brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/test/support/fixtures/cask/caffeines-subdir.zip: Could not stat brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/test/support/fixtures/cask/caffeines-subdir.zip
brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/test/support/fixtures/cask/caffeines.zip: Could not stat brew-1.7.1/Library/Homebrew/test/support/fixtures/cask/caffeines.zip
tar: Error reading 'brew-1.7.1.tar'Truncated input file (needed 3072 bytes, only 0 available)
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Here are the nfs mount options used :

```
nfs, nodev, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse
```

What can I ask the sysadmin regarding NFS to make things work ?

EDIT1 : The extraction works like a charm if I extract the tarball in a local filesystem like `/tmp`.

Comment: All I see there is a corrupted tarball.

Comment: @MarcWilson No it's not corrupted, please see the `tar tf` command and it's return code in the list of commands before the extraction.

Comment: @MarcWilson Please see my EDIT1.

Comment: Are you certain you can create files where you try to extract the tar ball?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen My $HOME is on NFS. `$ cd ~;touch toto;ls toto;`. I believe it's more of an NFS issue than a permission issue.

Comment: What did the sysadmin say when you asked what was the issue here?  This must be a well known problem.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'd love to contact him and ask the question but I don't have his cordinates by now for I'm doing my intership elsewhere.

Comment: Sounds like a machine that even though you "need" to install Homebrew, you are most likely not expected to (certainly not allowed to) especially as you cannot get hold of the person actually responsible for the well-being of said machine.   I would suggest you rethink your solution to your unstated problem.